# Solr Exception when using DataImportHandler: Exception in full dump while deleting all documents

Tags: java, exception, ubuntu, solr, tomcat6

I'm getting an error when trying to use Solr's DataImportHandler on Solr3.6. I've got the jar file in /etc/solr/dist and am running two cores at /etc/solr/core0 and /etc/solr/core1

Here's the Exception I'm seeing:

```
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:48 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [core1] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import} status=0 QTime=3 
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:48 AM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:48 AM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SimplePropertiesWriter readIndexerProperties
WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:48 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 deleteAll
INFO: [core1] REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:49 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=*:*} 0 3
Jun 19, 2013 9:43:49 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Exception in full dump while deleting all documents. Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:375)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:445)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:426)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Exception in full dump while deleting all documents. Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.doDeleteAll(SolrWriter.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.cleanByQuery(DocBuilder.java:1153)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:224)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/etc/solr/core1/data/index/write.lock: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/solr/core1/data/index/write.lock (Permission denied)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1098)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:101)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.deleteAll(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.deleteByQuery(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:324)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processDelete(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processDelete(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.doDeleteAll(SolrWriter.java:125)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/solr/core1/data/index/write.lock (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:95)
    ... 13 more
```

Here's my Solr Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_36</luceneMatchVersion>
  <lib dir="dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
  <!--  The DirectoryFactory to use for indexes.
        solr.StandardDirectoryFactory, the default, is filesystem based.
        solr.RAMDirectoryFactory is memory based, not persistent, and doesn't work with replication. -->
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}"/>
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2" />

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true" />
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler" />
  <requestHandler name="/admin/" class="org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers" />
      <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler> 
  <!-- config for the admin interface --> 
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>solr</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

Here's My Schema XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema name="deals" version="1.1">
  <types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="text_exact_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
  </types>

 <fields>   
  <!-- general -->
<field name="deal_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="headline" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="tagline" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="description" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="terms" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="start_date" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="end_date" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="price" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="value" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="discount_percentage" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="discount_value" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="category_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="url" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_name" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_phone" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_email" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_url" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="bullets" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_address" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="date_created" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="date_modified" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_city" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_zip" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="provider" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="provider_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="currency_code" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="clickthru" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="views" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="ord" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="is_deleted" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="category_suggest" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="image" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="merchant_state" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="slug" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="city_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="incomplete" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="group_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="start_date_2" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="end_date_2" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="block_national" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="removal_flag" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="provider_logo" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="approval_status" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="partner_id" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="city_name" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="special" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="old_cat" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="is_template" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="lat" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="lon" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="country" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

 </fields>

 <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
 <uniqueKey>deal_id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>headline</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
</schema>
```

Here's My data-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://#####/######" user="#####" password="#####" />
    <document name="Deals">
        <entity name="deal" query="SELECT * FROM deals">
            <field column="deal_id" name="deal_id" />
            <field column="headline" name="headline" />
            <field column="tagline" name="tagline" />
            <field column="description" name="description" />
            <field column="terms" name="terms" />
            <field column="start_date" name="start_date" />
            <field column="end_date" name="end_date" />
            <field column="price" name="price" />
            <field column="value" name="value" />
            <field column="discount_percentage" name="discount_percentage" />
            <field column="discount_value" name="discount_value" />
            <field column="category_id" name="category_id" />
            <field column="url" name="url" />
            <field column="merchant_name" name="merchant_name" />
            <field column="merchant_phone" name="merchant_phone" />
            <field column="merchant_email" name="merchant_email" />
            <field column="merchant_url" name="merchant_url" />
            <field column="bullets" name="bullets" />
            <field column="merchant_address" name="merchant_address" />
            <field column="date_created" name="date_created" />
            <field column="date_modified" name="date_modified" />
            <field column="merchant_city" name="merchant_city" />
            <field column="merchant_zip" name="merchant_zip" />
            <field column="provider" name="provider" />
            <field column="provider_id" name="provider_id" />
            <field column="currency_code" name="currency_code" />
            <field column="clickthru" name="clickthru" />
            <field column="views" name="views" />
            <field column="ord" name="ord" />
            <field column="is_deleted" name="is_deleted" />
            <field column="category_suggest" name="category_suggest" />
            <field column="image" name="image" />
            <field column="merchant_state" name="merchant_state" />
            <field column="slug" name="slug" />
            <field column="city_id" name="city_id" />
            <field column="incomplete" name="incomplete" />
            <field column="group_id" name="group_id" />
            <field column="start_date_2" name="start_date_2" />
            <field column="end_date_2" name="end_date_2" />
            <field column="block_national" name="block_national" />
            <field column="removal_flag" name="removal_flag" />
            <field column="provider_logo" name="provider_logo" />
            <field column="approval_status" name="approval_status" />
            <field column="partner_id" name="partner_id" />
            <field column="city_name" name="city_name" />
            <field column="special" name="special" />
            <field column="old_cat" name="old_cat" />
            <field column="is_template" name="is_template" />
            <field column="lat" name="lat" />
            <field column="lon" name="lon" />
            <field column="country" name="country" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I've run my xml files through validator and they all seem fine. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance - I've been trying to get this to work for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the below exception it looks like Solr is not able to delete the index because it does not have the rights.

`org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/etc/solr/core1/data/index/write.lock: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/solr/core1/data/index/write.lock (Permission denied)`

Give proper rights i.e. write and delete rights.